# How can I get both Scala and Java Cobertura coverage?

Tags: java, scala, jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura

I have a Scala project built with SBT. I use Jenkins to do my build, and include the following as a build target:

```
scoverage:test
```

This gets me very nice coverage reports for my Scala sources using the Cobertura plugin for Jenkins.

My project has Java files as well, however, and I get no coverage for them. If this were Maven, I'd know what to do. But being SBT, I'm a bit unclear on how I can get coverage for the Java sources and then ensure that Jenkins sees the output and displays it as well.

I do know that the Java tests run using "sbt test" so that's not an issue.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You want test coverage for both languages, joined together to make an integrated report?

Comment: can you post the build file?  also you said in maven you'd know what to do, so write that, maybe it will help someone to do the same using sbt.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, was out of town - yes, I'd love test coverage for both languages, joined together.

If this were Maven, I'd have a test target. But that's exactly what I'm asking about here - how is that done in SBT?